What is the difference between Ubuntu 24.04 Default (minimal) installation and Full installation?
I will be installing Ubuntu 24.04 when it releases in a few days, and there have been articles about the installer having two different choices: Default, which has "just the essentials, we browser and basic utilities" and the Full, which has "an offline-friendly selection of office tools, utilities, web browser and games".
None of the posts or videos goes into details. Obviously I know the basic difference, but everything is just generalized with "you get more".
What I want to know is the precise difference. As in, WHICH packages are going to be installed in the Full version and not in the Default version. Is there a list of such packages?

There is no exhaustive list of packages, full vs minimal, probably because most people don't care about such a list.

you know it is still Beta and what Beta vs. LTS means? Otherwise I suggest you read about them. There is this https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/ubuntu-desktop-minimal.

I believe the difference can be derived from the seed files

https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/ubuntu.noble/desktop
https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/ubuntu.noble/desktop-minimal

It appears the packages listed in the desktop seed file will be in addition to what is included in desktop-minimal.

Based on the app lists for ubuntu-desktop-minimal (1.539) and ubuntu-desktop (1.539) the following packages are included in the extended selection:

deja-dup: Backup utility
file-roller: archive manager for GNOME
gnome-calendar: Calendar application for GNOME
gnome-snapshot: Take pictures and videos from your webcam
libreoffice-calc: office productivity suite -- spreadsheet
libreoffice-gnome: office productivity suite -- GNOME integration
libreoffice-impress: office productivity suite -- presentation
libreoffice-math: office productivity suite -- equation editor
libreoffice-style-yaru: office productivity suite -- Yaru symbol style
libreoffice-writer: office productivity suite -- word processor
remmina: GTK+ Remote Desktop Client
rhythmbox: music player and organizer for GNOME
shotwell: digital photo organizer
simple-scan: Simple Scanning Utility
thunderbird [amd64, arm64]: Transitional package - thunderbird -> thunderbird snap
totem: Simple media player for the GNOME desktop based on GStreamer
transmission-gtk: lightweight BitTorrent client (GTK+ interface)
usb-creator-gtk [amd64]: create a startup disk using a CD or disc image (for GNOME)

